# Polybase In SQL server 2019 and 2022 take so long time

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, polybase

I'm using polybase to load data from PostgreSQL and have some problem
The PostgreSQl database and SQL server (for my case is SQL server 2022) are in same machine. I create an external table in SQL server to loading data from PostgreSQL database by Polybase, It's took at least over 1s even the table is empty and meanwhile i ran it in Pgadmin it run ok. I already Select only **id** column but it was same result.Here is some information:

1. When i run in pgadmin
   [image]
2. run with Linked Server
   [image]
   **As you can see it took only 329 ms**
3. I create table in SQL server

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[SaleorApp]
    (
        [id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [private_metadata] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [metadata] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [name] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
        [created_at] [datetime2](6) NOT NULL,
        [is_active] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
        [about_app] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [app_url] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
        [configuration_url] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
        [data_privacy] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [data_privacy_url] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
        [homepage_url] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
        [identifier] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
        [support_url] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
        [type] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
        [version] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
        [manifest_url] [nvarchar](200) NULL
    )
    WITH (DATA_SOURCE = [PostgreSQL35W],LOCATION = N'"saleor"."public"."app_app"')
```

After that i ran it in SQL server 2022

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
SELECT  [id]
      ,[private_metadata]
      ,[metadata]
      ,[name]
      ,[created_at]
      ,[is_active]
      ,[about_app]
      ,[app_url]
      ,[configuration_url]
      ,[data_privacy]
      ,[data_privacy_url]
      ,[homepage_url]
      ,[identifier]
      ,[support_url]
      ,[type]
      ,[version]
      ,[manifest_url]
  FROM [Pastaxi].[dbo].[SaleorApp]
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
```

And it ruturned :

**SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 940 ms.**

I already checked in Polybase log and here is result:

```
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:2304] [PdwTdsNativeToManagedInterop:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Incoming TDS connection, Client TDS version: 7 (TDS74). 
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:2304] [EngineInstrumentation:TdsAddConnectionEvent] (Info, Low): Starting TDS connection: 1929345925184 Client: 192.168.1.22:63040, isFromDataSecurityProxy: False, isVnetAddress: False, clientAddressSafe: 192.168.1.22:63040 
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:2304] [DataClassificationConfig:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Returning FeatureSwitch DataClassificationCoreEnabled status: False [Session.SessionId:SID3170][Session.IsTransactional:False]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:2304] [EngineInstrumentation:ServerStartSessionEvent] (Info, Low): Started new session, in reset connection: False. [Session.SessionId:SID3170][Session.IsTransactional:False]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:2304] [TdsRequestProcessor:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Processing login, authentication scheme: "SqlAuthentication", client application name: "C39A9D00-5206-85DF-3907-338474E48E80" 
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:2304] [PdwTdsNativeToManagedInterop:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Data Classification TDS Extension Requested=False, FS Enabled=False, Enabled=False. [Session.SessionId:SID3170][Session.IsTransactional:True][Query.QueryId:QID3294]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:1940] [EngineInstrumentation:TdsAddConnectionEvent] (Info, Low): Starting TDS connection: 1929427025984 Client: , isFromDataSecurityProxy: False, isVnetAddress: False, clientAddressSafe:  
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:13664] [EngineInstrumentation:EngineStopSessionBeginEvent] (Info, Low): Stopping session, in reset connection: False. [Session.SessionId:SID3170][Session.IsTransactional:False]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:13664] [EngineInstrumentation:TdsRemoveConnectionEvent] (Info, Low): Stopping TDS connection: 1929427025984 
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:2304] [TdsRequestProcessor:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): CancelBatch request started [Session.SessionId:SID3170] 
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:2304] [TdsRequestProcessor:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): CancelBatch request started [Session.SessionId:SID3170] 
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:3860] [EngineInstrumentation:EngineCancelQueryBeginEvent] (Info, Low): Cancel requested. [Session.SessionId:SID3170][Session.IsTransactional:False]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:2288] [EngineInstrumentation:EngineCancelQueryBeginEvent] (Info, Low): Cancel requested. [Session.SessionId:SID3170][Session.IsTransactional:False]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:13664] [EngineInstrumentation:TdsRemoveConnectionEvent] (Info, Low): Stopping TDS connection: 1929345925184 
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:13664] [EngineInstrumentation:EngineStopSessionBeginEvent] (Info, Low): Stopping session, in reset connection: False. [Session.SessionId:SID3170][Session.IsTransactional:False]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:2304] [PdwTdsNativeToManagedInterop:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Incoming TDS connection, Client TDS version: 7 (TDS74). 
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:2304] [EngineInstrumentation:TdsAddConnectionEvent] (Info, Low): Starting TDS connection: 1929345925184 Client: 192.168.1.22:63041, isFromDataSecurityProxy: False, isVnetAddress: False, clientAddressSafe: 192.168.1.22:63041 
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:2304] [DataClassificationConfig:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Returning FeatureSwitch DataClassificationCoreEnabled status: False [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:2304] [EngineInstrumentation:ServerStartSessionEvent] (Info, Low): Started new session, in reset connection: False. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:2304] [TdsRequestProcessor:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Processing login, authentication scheme: "SqlAuthentication", client application name: "C39A9D00-5206-85DF-3907-338474E48E80" 
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:2304] [PdwTdsNativeToManagedInterop:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Data Classification TDS Extension Requested=False, FS Enabled=False, Enabled=False. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:True][Query.QueryId:QID3295]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:1940] [EngineInstrumentation:TdsAddConnectionEvent] (Info, Low): Starting TDS connection: 1929427025984 Client: , isFromDataSecurityProxy: False, isVnetAddress: False, clientAddressSafe:  
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:2304] [ServerInterface:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Incoming Query:  SID3171:QID3296 [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:3860] [ServerInterface:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Starting processor ExecuteMemoProcessor. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:3860] [OptimizedStatement:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Memo compilation time: 2.0026 ms [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:3860] [OptimizedStatement:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Sql Server Optimization Clock: 0.001 s, CPU: 0.001 s. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:3860] [OptimizedStatement:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): SQL Server XML generation Clock : 0.001 s, CPU: 0.001 s [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:3860] [NativeOdbcConnection:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): NativeOdbcConnection.Open, ConnectionString: Dsn=PostgreSQL35W;uid=saleor;server=localhost;port=5432, CreateOptions: ReadExternal, PacketSize: 0, EnableConnectionPooling: True, TransactionPropagationToken: null, ResourceGroup: null [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:3860] [NativeOdbcConnection:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): NativeOdbcConnection.Open, ConnectionString: Dsn=PostgreSQL35W;uid=saleor;server=localhost;port=5432, CreateOptions: ReadExternal, PacketSize: 0, EnableConnectionPooling: True, TransactionPropagationToken: null, ResourceGroup: null [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:3860] [NativeOdbcConnection:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): NativeOdbcConnection.Open, ConnectionString: Dsn=PostgreSQL35W;uid=saleor;server=localhost;port=5432, CreateOptions: ReadExternal, PacketSize: 0, EnableConnectionPooling: True, TransactionPropagationToken: null, ResourceGroup: null [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:3860] [NativeOdbcConnection:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): NativeOdbcConnection.Open, ConnectionString: Dsn=PostgreSQL35W;uid=saleor;server=localhost;port=5432;database=saleor, CreateOptions: ReadExternal, PacketSize: 0, EnableConnectionPooling: True, TransactionPropagationToken: null, ResourceGroup: null [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:3860] [NativeOdbcConnection:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): NativeOdbcConnection.Open, ConnectionString: Dsn=PostgreSQL35W;uid=saleor;server=localhost;port=5432;database=saleor, CreateOptions: ReadExternal, PacketSize: 0, EnableConnectionPooling: True, TransactionPropagationToken: null, ResourceGroup: null [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:3860] [NativeOdbcConnection:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): NativeOdbcConnection.Open, ConnectionString: Dsn=PostgreSQL35W;uid=saleor;server=localhost;port=5432;database=saleor, CreateOptions: ReadExternal, PacketSize: 0, EnableConnectionPooling: True, TransactionPropagationToken: null, ResourceGroup: null [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:3860] [NativeOdbcConnection:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): NativeOdbcConnection.Open, ConnectionString: Dsn=PostgreSQL35W;uid=saleor;server=localhost;port=5432;database=saleor, CreateOptions: ReadExternal, PacketSize: 0, EnableConnectionPooling: True, TransactionPropagationToken: null, ResourceGroup: null [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:54 AM [Thread:3860] [NativeOdbcConnection:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): NativeOdbcConnection.Open, ConnectionString: Dsn=PostgreSQL35W;uid=saleor;server=localhost;port=5432;database=saleor, CreateOptions: ReadExternal, PacketSize: 0, EnableConnectionPooling: True, TransactionPropagationToken: null, ResourceGroup: null [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [NativeOdbcConnection:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): NativeOdbcConnection.Open, ConnectionString: Dsn=PostgreSQL35W;uid=saleor;server=localhost;port=5432;database=saleor, CreateOptions: ReadExternal, PacketSize: 0, EnableConnectionPooling: True, TransactionPropagationToken: null, ResourceGroup: null [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [ExecuteMemoStatement:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Operation on External Table [SaleorApp] with LOB columns : Columns 17, LOBColumns 4, LOBStringColumns 4. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [LimitNumberOfScaOpConst:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): The number of literals in the query: 0. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [OptimizedStatement:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Distributed QO time: 728.4171 ms [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [DMSPlanBuilder:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Loading into a table with Small resource class: Parallel writers will be disabled during this operation. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [DMSPlanBuilder:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Loading into a table with Small resource class: Parallel writers will be disabled during this operation. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [DMSPlanBuilder:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Loading into a table with Small resource class: Parallel writers will be disabled during this operation. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [DMSPlanBuilder:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Loading into a table with Small resource class: Parallel writers will be disabled during this operation. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [DMSPlanBuilder:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Loading into a table with Small resource class: Parallel writers will be disabled during this operation. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [DMSPlanBuilder:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Loading into a table with Small resource class: Parallel writers will be disabled during this operation. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [DMSPlanBuilder:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Loading into a table with Small resource class: Parallel writers will be disabled during this operation. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [DMSPlanBuilder:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Loading into a table with Small resource class: Parallel writers will be disabled during this operation. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [DMSPlanBuilder:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Loading into a table with Small resource class: Parallel writers will be disabled during this operation. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [DMSPlanBuilder:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Loading into a table with Small resource class: Parallel writers will be disabled during this operation. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [DMSPlanBuilder:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Loading into a table with Small resource class: Parallel writers will be disabled during this operation. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [DMSPlanBuilder:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Loading into a table with Small resource class: Parallel writers will be disabled during this operation. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [DMSPlanBuilder:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Loading into a table with Small resource class: Parallel writers will be disabled during this operation. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [DMSPlanBuilder:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Loading into a table with Small resource class: Parallel writers will be disabled during this operation. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [DMSPlanBuilder:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Loading into a table with Small resource class: Parallel writers will be disabled during this operation. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [DMSPlanBuilder:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Loading into a table with Small resource class: Parallel writers will be disabled during this operation. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [DMSManager:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): ExecuteCommand Query:SID3171 Plan:3e7c8916-13e2-41c2-a8cf-8c32837d290f [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [DMSManager:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): DMS Manager starting query: SID3171, plan: 3e7c8916-13e2-41c2-a8cf-8c32837d290f. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [AbstractDataMovementExecutable`1:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): DMS Manager finishing query: SID3171, plan: 3e7c8916-13e2-41c2-a8cf-8c32837d290f, queryId: QID3296 [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:3860] [ServerInterface:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Query SID3171:QID3296 completed. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False][Query.QueryId:QID3296]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:1940] [EngineInstrumentation:TdsAddConnectionEvent] (Info, Low): Starting TDS connection: 1929427042368 Client: , isFromDataSecurityProxy: False, isVnetAddress: False, clientAddressSafe:  
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:2304] [EngineInstrumentation:EngineStopSessionBeginEvent] (Info, Low): Stopping session, in reset connection: False. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:2304] [EngineInstrumentation:TdsRemoveConnectionEvent] (Info, Low): Stopping TDS connection: 1929427025984 
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:5232] [EngineInstrumentation:TdsRemoveConnectionEvent] (Info, Low): Stopping TDS connection: 1929427042368 
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:2512] [TdsRequestProcessor:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): CancelBatch request started [Session.SessionId:SID3171] 
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:2288] [EngineInstrumentation:EngineCancelQueryBeginEvent] (Info, Low): Cancel requested. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False]
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:2512] [EngineInstrumentation:TdsRemoveConnectionEvent] (Info, Low): Stopping TDS connection: 1929345925184 
12/3/2022 10:15:55 AM [Thread:2512] [EngineInstrumentation:EngineStopSessionBeginEvent] (Info, Low): Stopping session, in reset connection: False. [Session.SessionId:SID3171][Session.IsTransactional:False]
```

I don't know why that is, any help for me???
Thanks for watching

Comment: What happens if you just use a normal Linked Server instead? 940 ms is probably somewhat reasonable for communicating across the network via whichever driver Polybase is using, to your PostgreSQL server, especially if the table natively runs in 329 ms directly in your PostgreSQL server, with no data in it. I would definitely not call it a long time.

Comment: @J.D. I already use Linked Server, it even faster than query in Pgadmin. Just took 5ms

Comment: And Polybase is still slower after? If the Linked Server is that much faster than your one run that was directly on the PostgreSQL server, it sounds more like an intermittent or unrelated issue to SQL Server.

Comment: @J.D. as I know and as you see in the log above (in polybase movement engine log), each time polybase query, it's will etablish connection with PostgreSQL database,set up all relevant configurations (it's located in DWConfiguration database) then just execute query without any caching. I don't know how to caching the execution for the next query...

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of caching you expect, but Polybase works almost essentially the same as a Linked Server, for what it's worth.

Comment: I don't understand the expectations that you have in this scenario. It goes from 300ms to 900ms after adding in 2 more layers of indirection. Seems normal. Are you expecting to add in a middle layer of software and not have it take more time than direct?

Comment: @SeanGallardy I just add a new image compared between polybase with linked server,elapsed time polybase is 943ms while linked server is 6ms...

Comment: Again, you expect a whole set of external executables and own execution environment to be the same speed as something built in? I don't see a problem in the timing here, personally. I believe there are unrealistic expectations of same performance from multiple extra layers of processing.